# Change string value. C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How do i change a string value of

```
http://host/index.php?p=page
```

to

```
http://host/index.php?p=
```

Comment: Can you be more specific - do you want to get string values up to the ending `=` sign?

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible.

In .NET strings are immutable, which means that you can't change a string.

What you can do is to create a new string value from the original, for example by copying all of the string except the last four characters:

```
url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, since you aren't being to clear here, but this does what you ask.

```
string value = @"http://host/index.php?p=page";
value = @"http://host/index.php?p=";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s=@"http://host/index.php?p=page";

s=@"http://host/index.php?p=";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = @"http://host/index.php?p=page";
s = s.Replace("page", "");
```

Or, more seriously, you probably want:

```
string s = @"http://host/index.php?p=page";
s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood your question, will remove anything after the last "="

```
string s = @"http://host/index.php?p=page";
s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf("=")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strip off everything after the first "=" character:

```
string s = @"http://host/index.php?p=page"
s = s.Split('=')[0] + "=";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more way:

```
String oldString = "http://host/index.php?p=page";
String newString = oldString.Substring(0, oldString.IndexOf("?p=") + 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're lookin to "parameterize" the string.

```
String.Format("http://host/index.php?p={0}", variableName);
```